# Tag merge request [large-data] and [bigdata]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The two tags [large-data](/questions/tagged/large-data) and [bigdata](/questions/tagged/bigdata) describe the same thing, therefore I would be in favor of merging them. I would suggest using [bigdata](/questions/tagged/bigdata) because this is the buzzword that is currently used a lot.

Comment: Nope - two different tags. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they mean they same thing.  [large-data](/questions/tagged/large-data) seems to cover the use of "regular" software (Spreadsheets, Web servers, etc.) in dealing with very large data sets. [big-data](/questions/tagged/big-data) covers a different set of topics. namely the use of software products that were designed to be parallel and scalable in the first place.

[large-data](/questions/tagged/large-data) should probably be kept as-is since it does indicate a special kind of problem.

[bigdata](/questions/tagged/bigdata) could be nuked as it's very general, much like the [database](/questions/tagged/database) tag.

Comment: I don't see any distinction. Big Data is the popular industry term for large data. Large data is what someone calls it when they don't know that everyone is calling it Big Data. FWIW I am a professional in this area.

Answer (score -3):

As [it's a buzzword](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151955/what-is-the-definition-of-big-data) I'd be in favour of removing them both. A buzzword has no meaning. To quote from [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buzzword):

> 1: an important-sounding usually technical word or phrase often of
>   little meaning used chiefly to impress laymen
>   2: a voguish word or phrase —called also buzz phrase

Or, perhaps more appropriately from the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=buzz%20word) (I know this isn't a canonical resource but I couldn't resist...)

> A seemingly intelligent word that dumb people use to sound smart

A tag with no meaning has no use and so should be burninated and blacklisted if it returns.

Failing that, and reducing my Cabal tendencies somewhat, if they're going to be kept around they should probably be synonymised to [big-data](/questions/tagged/big-data), which doesn't yet exist but is more in keeping with the current practice of using a hyphen to split words in tag names.

Comment: I agree with merging them to be [tag:big-data] as opposed to outright deleting them, since it's a legitimate topic, despite it being one that's not always clearly defined.